# install4j uninstall previous installation

Tags: user-input, updates, install4j

I am creating an update for an application built in install4j and I want to overwrite the files in the installation directory but keeping the configutation files. I manually edited some of them to never be overwriten but I cannot keep the files created by user input when installing it for the first time.

Is it possible to set a condition in the "Uninstall previous installation" so that it keeps the user's input? The user's input does not exist in the distribution tree. This means that I cannot manually edit it so that it is never uninstalled.

Comment: What are "files created by user input"? install4j will not delete any files it did not create itself unless you use a "Delete files and directories" action.

Comment: I am sorry, I was not clear. I meant the response file.

Comment: What I want it to load the response file and copy it to another directory while updating. Then I uninstall the previous installation. I know that the response file is not being deleted, but can I copy it in another directory with the "Copy files and directories" action?

Comment: Sure, you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to move the file? The response file you either load if it is an update or leave install4j to delete it.
The file is usually loaded on updates to use some variable the user set in the initial install, like a username, so you won't have to ask him again.